# "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to false" - SonarQube

Tags: java, tree, sonarqube

I have this following code and I'm getting a SonarQube

> Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to false

This line of code `if(hashCodeVariable == null && equalsVariable.equals(EQUALS_METHOD)) {` is the one that gives me the sonarqube error.

```
@Override
  public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
    MethodTree mt = null;
    ClassTree classTree = (ClassTree) tree;
    if (!hasSemantic()) {
      return;
    }
    for (Tree memberTree : classTree.members()) {
      if (memberTree.kind().name().equals(Kind.METHOD.name())) {
        mt = (MethodTree) memberTree;
        methods.add(mt);
      }
    }
    storeMethodValue(mt);
  }

  public void storeMethodValue(MethodTree mt) {
    String methodName;
    try {
      for (MethodTree method : methods) {
        methodName = PUBLIC + SPACE + method.returnType().symbolType().name()
            + SPACE + method.symbol().name();
        checkMethodName(methodName);
      }
      if(hashCodeVariable.equals(HASH_CODE_METHOD) && equalsVariable == null) {
        reportIssue(mt, "in");
        return;
      }

      if(hashCodeVariable == null && equalsVariable.equals(EQUALS_METHOD)) {
        reportIssue(mt, "out");
        return;
      }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException nullPointer) {
      throw nullPointer;
    }
  }

  public void checkMethodName(String methodName) {
    if (methodName.equals(EQUALS_METHOD)) {
      equalsVariable = methodName;
    } else if (methodName.equals(HASH_CODE_METHOD)) {
      hashCodeVariable = methodName;
    }
  }
```

To those who are knowledgeable in using `Tree`, is my code somewhat okay? And what changes should I do?

Answer (score 3):

The test on null for hashCodeVariable is senseless as in the first case one has used .equals on it.

```
 if(hashCodeVariable.equals(HASH_CODE_METHOD) && equalsVariable == null) {
 ...
 if(hashCodeVariable == null && equalsVariable.equals(EQUALS_METHOD)) {
```

hashCodeVariable is !null, as otherwise in the first if-statement would have raised a NullPointerException. So the condition is false.

Answer (score 2):

At that point `hashCodeVariable` is non-null because otherwise a `NullPointerException` would have been thrown in the previous if-block. That condition is `false`. `&&` is short-circuited so `false && whatever` is `false`, without evaluating whatever.